How to nest lambdas and run them in the same line?
Currently trying to nest two lambdas (where the variable for one lambda is defined as the second) and I keep getting an error.
print((lambda  x: x*3) (lambda y: 5*y) (int(input())))
When I run this, it throws an error, citing that "*" is an unsupported operator for a function and integer.
How would I help the code understand that the second lambda is an integer?
I know this is rather excessive, but I'm trying to keep it to one line for the memes. I understand if this isn't possible, it's just more fun that way.

"How would I help the code understand that the second lambda is an integer?" - it's not. What gave you the idea that it is?

@user2357112 I'm hoping that I can tell the code that the second lambda returns an integer so I can use it in the first lambda

Were you expecting (x)(y)(z) to call x on (y)(z)? It calls x on y.

@user2357112 My goal is to set x equal to the value of the second lambda once it's evaluated... is that what you're asking? I'm sorry, I'm a little confused

"I'm trying to keep it to one line for the memes." what does that mean?

IIUC, you can add brackets:
print((lambda x: x * 3)((lambda y: 5 * y)(int(input()))))

